# How to Login my ASP.NET MVC website through Facebook Login

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, facebook

I want to add facebook login button into my ASP.NET MVC website
and I am getting error:

> API Error Code: 191
>   API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
>   Error Message: Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.

Comment: Does your redirect_uri start with with _Settings_ -> _Basic_ -> _Website with Facebook Login_ -> _Site URL_?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are going with the [Server-Side Authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/) route. This error means the domain of your `redirect_url` parameter is not listed in your Facebook App's "App Domains" list.

So either you entered redirect URL incorrectly in your OAuth dialog link, or the proper domain is not listed in your app's "App Domains" list.  It is recommended you enter a wildcard domain in your app's App Domains list (e.g., example.com) so subdomains are included (e.g., www.example.com, blog.example.com)

You can view your Facebook App's App Domains by going to Settings -> Basic -> Basic Info.